# vertical spacing not constant, if i change number of rows in subplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

i created a dataframe with dummy values like this:

```
data = {f'Col-{i}': np.random.randint(1, 101, size=100) for i in range(1, 21)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now i am trying to make a figure with a grid of subplots:

```
def generate_subplot_grid(n_rows, n_cols, cols_to_plot, subplot_height=200, subplot_width=300, vertical_spacing=0.1):
    # Calculate total figure width and height based on subplot dimensions and fixed vertical spacing
    total_width = n_cols * subplot_width
    total_height = (n_rows * subplot_height) + (n_rows - 1) * subplot_height * vertical_spacing

    # Create a subplot grid with specified subplot dimensions and fixed vertical spacing
    fig = make_subplots(rows=n_rows, cols=n_cols, subplot_titles=cols_to_plot, 
                        vertical_spacing=vertical_spacing,
                        row_heights=[subplot_height] * n_rows,
                        column_widths=[subplot_width] * n_cols)

    # Loop through the columns to be plotted and add them to subplots
    for i, col_name in enumerate(cols_to_plot):
        row = (i // n_cols) + 1
        col = (i % n_cols) + 1
        trace = go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6], mode='lines', name=col_name)
        fig.add_trace(trace, row=row, col=col)

    # Update layout to set the total figure width and height
    fig.update_layout(
        title_text="Subplot Grid Example",
        width=total_width,
        height=total_height
    )
    
    return fig

cols_to_plot = ["Col-1", "Col-2", "Col-3", "Col-4", "Col-5", "Col-6", "Col-7"]
#  cols_to_plot = df.columns

n_cols = 3
n_rows = (len(cols_to_plot) + n_cols - 1) // n_cols

subplot_height = 200  # Set your desired subplot height in pixels
subplot_width = 300   # Set your desired subplot width in pixels

vertical_spacing = 0.1  # Set your desired vertical spacing

subplot_fig = generate_subplot_grid(n_rows, n_cols, cols_to_plot, subplot_height, subplot_width, vertical_spacing)

subplot_fig.show()
```

When i try plotting on seven columns, versus if i plot all the 20 column, the vertical space between subplots also keep changing.

I tried including or excluding the "vertical_Spacing" out of "total figure height". But it does not work.

Comment: Welcome ! where is this function `make_subplots` ?

Comment: thats plotly inbuilt funtion